# How to use dynamic where clause in EXECUTE IMMEDIATE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table with columns insert,select,where clause,dynamic where clause,group by clause.

Using procedure i need to execute insert into statement and also use dynamic where clause.

I tried the following one however it is giving me an error missing expression.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE dynamicWhereClause(Datee IN DATE,processId IN NUMBER)
IS 

 processName VARCHAR2(100);
 tablePrefix CONFIG_DETAILS.SOURCE_TABLE%Type;
 sourceTableType CONFIG_DETAILS.SOURCE_TABLE_TYPE%Type;
 insertClause CONFIG_DETAILS.INSERT_CLAUSE%Type;
 selectClause CONFIG_DETAILS.SELECT_CLAUSE%Type;
 whereClause CONFIG_DETAILS.WHERE_CLAUSE%Type;
 onUpdateClause CONFIG_DETAILS.ON_UPDATE_CLAUSE%Type;
 groupByClause CONFIG_DETAILS.GROUP_BY_CLAUSE%Type;
 orderByClause CONFIG_DETAILS.ORDER_BY_CLAUSE%Type;
 isDynamicWhereClause CONFIG_DETAILS.IS_DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE%Type;
 tableName VARCHAR2(50);
 Process_Date DATE;
 processQuery VARCHAR2(6000 BYTE);


 CURSOR Process_Report IS 
    select NAME,SOURCE_TABLE,SOURCE_TABLE_TYPE,INSERT_CLAUSE,SELECT_CLAUSE,WHERE_CLAUSE,ON_UPDATE_CLAUSE,GROUP_BY_CLAUSE,ORDER_BY_CLAUSE,IS_DYNAMIC_WHERE_CLAUSE FROM 
    CONFIG_DETAILS where ID=processId;

BEGIN

    OPEN Process_Report;
    LOOP

        FETCH Process_Report INTO processName,tablePrefix,sourceTableType,insertClause,selectClause,whereClause,onUpdateClause,groupByClause,orderByClause,isDynamicWhereClause;
            EXIT when Process_Report%NOTFOUND;

        tableName := getSourceTableName(tablePrefix,sourceTableType,processDate);
        Process_Date := processDate;

        processQuery := insertClause || selectClause ||' from ' || tableName ||' ' ||
        nvl(whereClause,'') ||''||nvl(groupByClause,'') ||''||nvl(orderByClause,'') ||''||nvl(onUpdateClause,'');

        dbms_output.put_line(processQuery);

        IF isDynamicWhereClause = 'Y' 
        THEN
            dbms_output.put_line(processQuery);
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE processQuery USING Process_Date;  

        ELSE

            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  processQuery;

        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE Process_Report;

END;
```

While executing the proc it is giving me the below error.

```
Error report -
ORA-00936: missing expression
ORA-06512: at "Mytest.dynamicWhereClause", line 44
ORA-06512: at line 1
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
```

Please assist me further

Thanks

Comment: Did you check what `dbms_output.put_line(processQuery);` produces? Don't `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` anything, unless you're sure that `processQuery` is OK.

Comment: Just print out your resulting `processQuery` to see what is going on. It seems that  your `CONFIG_DETAILS` table contains invalid data e.g. `Mytest.dynamicWhereClause` instead of actual `where` clause...

Comment: `NVL(variable, '')` is pointless, just use the `variable`.

Comment: `ORDER BY` clause is also useless for an INSERT statement.

Comment: @Littlefoot the query is printing exactly what I want how ever it is not taking where clause, it is printing as `where Date =` here I need to pass the `Process_Date DATE`

Comment: Please show us the full dynamic query.

Comment: @Littlefoot Please check this `insert into DETAIL(ID,DATEE,NAME)
select ID,DATEE,NAME from CC_08 where DATEE=`

Comment: @Ram after date there is no variable ?  process_date containing data ?

Comment: I'm not sure *what* could I (or anyone else) check. Obviously, date value is missing, but I have no idea why. You didn't concatenate it. Why? Maybe it is missing in the WHERE clause you're selecting; how could I know?

Comment: The string must be like `insert into DETAIL(ID,DATEE,NAME) select ID,DATEE,NAME from CC_08 where DATEE= :dateValue`

Comment: What is the actual value of `CONFIG_DETAILS.WHERE_CLAUSE` for the row you are processing? By the way, the code would be a lot easier to read if it used a standard [Cursor FOR loop](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/cursor_for_loop_statement.htm) instead of the verbose version.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions is not 100% clear . you saying after `DATEE` is being empty, are you assigning a variable after date ? the below is example of how using execute immediate with a variable. Note how is the bind variable `:i` is showing in the print.

```
set serveroutput on size 1000 
/
declare t number(4) :=10;
txt varchar2(100);
begin
txt :='INSERT INTO TAB (ID) values (:i)';
dbms_output.put_line(t || ' ' || txt);
execute immediate txt using T;
end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

10 INSERT INTO TAB (ID) values (:i)
```